# AngularJs - How to access controller's function and model in directive

Tags: angularjs

Hi i have imlemented directives many time, each time i have to bind each property, function etc.Like this

```
app.directive('postJobWizard', function () {

return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
        'artistSearchModel': "=",
        'showDropdown': "=",
        'operaticRoleSearchResult': "=",
        'viewAllJobs': "&",
        'getSingleJob':"&",
        'musicalWorkSearchResult': "=",
        'institutionSearchResult': "=",
        'changeTypeOfFilter': "&",
        'searchArtistJob': "&",
        'placeOfSearch':"@placeOfSearch",
        'artistFilterSearch':'=',
        'dropDownTitles':'=',
        'searchPlaceHolder':'@searchPlaceHolder',
        'isArtistOrAos':'=',
        'noResultFound' : '=',
        'oppurtunityOrBoard':'@',
        'oppurtunitiesOrBoards':'@',
        'showInfoIcon' : '=',
        'infoIconText' : '='
        },
    controller: function () { },
    controllerAs: '$postJob',
    bindToController: true,
    templateUrl: '/views/tss/directives/postJobWizard.html'
};
```

});

But lets suppose i have 50 functions and 100s of models, i have to write each of them in `scope`. Is there any way or best practice by which we can access parents controller functions and models.  Please explain will it be the best practice ?

Comment: I think that having 50 function and 100 model would be wrong design from the start but on your question you can add {'showInfoIcon' : '=',
        'infoIconText' : '=', ....rest of your bindings } in a constant and load it

Answer (score 1):

inject constant like this:

```
app
.constant('scopeSettings',{your scope object goes here (probably on a seperate file)})
.directive('postJobWizard', function (scopeSettings) {

return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: scopeSettings,
    controller: function () { },
    controllerAs: '$postJob',
    bindToController: true,
    templateUrl: '/views/tss/directives/postJobWizard.html'
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a little snippet that can hopefully set you in the right direction. Also have a look at [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) link to learn more about directives and how the scopes and controllers work.

```js
(function() {
 'use strict';
  
  angular.module('myApp', []);
  
  angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', MyController);
  
  MyController.$inject = [];
  function MyController() {
   var main = this;
    
    main.thisFunctionIsPublic = thisFunctionIsPublic;
    
   function thisFunctionIsPublic() {
     return 'This text comes straight from the parent controller!';
    }
  
   function thisFunctionIsPrivate() {
     return 'private!';
    }
  }
  
  angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function() {
   return {
     restrict: 'E',
      scope: false,
      controllerAs: '$controller',
      //bindToController: true,
      template: '<p>Public function: {{$controller.parentController.thisFunctionIsPublic()}}</p><p>Private function: {{$controller.parentController.thisFunctionIsPrivate()}}</p>',
      controller: function($element) {
       this.parentController = $element.parent().controller();
        console.log(this.parentController);
      }
    };
  });
  
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController as main">
    <my-directive></my-directive>
  </div>
</body>
```

**DISCLAIMER:** I don't think this is best practice as I believe directives should mostly be stand alone pieces of code that should be able to work regardless of what resides on the parent controller, but this is how I would access the parent controller if I REALLY needed to.